# find the range of function $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus

find the range of function $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$

My Try : $$x^2 \geq 0 \\x^2+1\geq1 \\ \sqrt{x^2+1}\geq1$$
Now what ?

Comment: @Ak19: one also has $\sqrt{x^2+1}>|x|$.

Comment: can you show for $x<0, x+\sqrt{x^2+1}>0$?

Comment: @NoChance:  the domain is all numbers, but what is the image?

Comment: @NoChance: you are talking about the "domain", not the "range" of the function.

Comment: @Jack and J.W. Tanner thanks for your comment. You are correct.

Comment: @jack Sorry, you're right.

Comment: Note:  for $x\ge0, x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\ge1$

Answer (score 3):

This is a continuous  increasing function with $$\lim _{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f( x)=\infty$$

Thus the range is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: I believe one needs more: one can construct a function $f$ that has the mentioned limiting behavior but has a range that is not $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: The function is also increasing.

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=e^x$ for $x\in(-\infty,0)$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$, (1) is increasing (2) satisfies $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. But the range of $f$ is not $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Your function is not continuous

Comment: In your original argument, you did not mention "continuity". I agree now that you have a correct answer. Yet, it is nontrivial to prove the statement in you answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer and mentioned continuity. Your counter example was very helpful.

Comment: My +1 for your edit.

Comment: Thanks for your deep attention and helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $x=\cot2y,0<2y<\pi$

$f=x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=\cdots=\cot y$

Now $0<y<\dfrac\pi2$

$\cot0>f>\cot\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $\Bbb R$ as there are no restrictions. However, the range of $f(x)$ is not $\Bbb R$. For $x\ge0$, the range is clearly $[1,\infty)$. For $x<0$, let $k=-x>0$. Then the function $$f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\implies g(k)=-k+\sqrt{k^2+1}>0$$ for all positive $k$. Thus the range is $(0,1)\cup[1,\infty)=(0,\infty)$.

Comment: The constant function $f(x)=1$ satisfies that (1) for $x\ge 0$, $f(x)\ge 1$; (2) for  all $x<0$, $f(x)>0$. But the range of this function is not the same as the one in OP.

Comment: @Jack Good point, I have edited the post to make this slightly more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{x^2+1}>|x|$, which implies that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the range of $f$ must be a subset of $(0,\infty)$.

To show that $(0,\infty)$ *is* the range of $f$, consider any $b>0$. Now you want to show that there exists some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Note that if $b=f(a)$, then
$$
(b-a)^2=a^2+1
$$
and thus
$$
b^2-2ab=1.
$$
Consequently, you can check by substitution that $a=\frac{b^2-1}{2b}$ is such that $f(a)=b$.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider only the positive magnitude of the sqrt,then the range of the function is(0,infinity).
As simplifire made it for positive domain,I would like to give you for negative domain.
When you consider the function with negative domain,the difference between x and sqrt(x^2+1) varies from 0 to1.The value is 1 when x is 0 and decreases to 0 when x is -infintiy,but never approaches 0,because the value under sqrt is always greater than x.
If one consider both + and - sqrt then it is not a function at all.Since a function can't have two outputs for single input.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x^2}= |x| \implies \sqrt{x^2+1}> |x|\geq -x$

So, $x+\sqrt{x^2+1}> 0$

Then, the range of $f(x) \subseteq  ]0,+\infty[$

Also since, $f$ is a continuous function and 
$\lim _{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$ and 
$\lim_{x\to \infty} f( x)=+\infty$

Thus, the range of $f(x)$ is $]0,+\infty[$

Comment: The constant function $f(x)\equiv 1$ satisfies $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. But its range is $\{1\}$, not $]0,+\infty[$.

Comment: You're right @Jack it only means that it is a subset of $]0,+\infty[$

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=e^x$ for $x\in(-\infty,0)$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$, satisfies (1)$\textrm{range}(f)\subset(0,\infty)$; (2)$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. But the range of $f$ is not $(0,\infty)$.